# How to set VerticalScrollPane to only tabs in JtabbedPane when more number of tabs are there?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I have one TabbedPane, where i have 100 tabs displaying in tabbedpane. Because of that i am unable to see content of tabs.If there are few tabs iam able to see the content when i click on particular tab.So i want to provide vertical scrollpane to only tabs.

```
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane          =   new JTabbedPane();
private void addTabForFiles(String fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            TextPanel panel = new TextPanel();
            tabbedPane.addTab(fileName, panel);     
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
tabbedPane.setTabLayoutPolicy( JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT )
```

Comment: But it is showing as horizantal scrollbar,I want it as vertical scrollbar

Comment: @srinivas, Then change the tab position to have the tabs on the right. Read the API to learn how to use the component.